# Why the dom element not updating it's innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml, createelement

The dom element stays the same even if I change the height or weight to make bmi underweight. How can I make the p element change dynamically when the BMI changes?

Here is the JS:

```js
let heightEl = document.getElementById("height");
let weightEl = document.getElementById("weight");

let bmidisplayEl = document.getElementById("bmi-value");

let bmisubmitEl = document.getElementById("bmi-submit");

bmisubmitEl.addEventListener("click",bmiCalc);

export default function bmiCalc(){
    let heightSquare =Math.pow(Number(heightEl.value), 2);
    let bmiResult = Math.floor(Number(weightEl.value)*703/heightSquare);
    let bmiStatus = document.createElement("p");
    bmiStatus.setAttribute("id","bmistatus");

    bmidisplayEl.innerHTML =`Your bmi is ${bmiResult}`;

    if (bmiResult <= 18.5){
        bmiStatus.innerHTML=`Underweight`;
    }else if(bmiResult =>25){
        bmiStatus.innerHTML=`Overweight`;
    }
    else{
        bmiStatus.innerHTML=`Healthy`;
    }
    const bmiBody = document.getElementById("bmi");
    bmiBody.appendChild(bmiStatus);

}
```

and here is the html:

```html
<div id="bmi">
            <h1>BMI Calculator</h1> 
            <div id="bmi-form-container">
                <form action="" onsubmit="event.preventDefault()" >
                    <div id="top-row">
                        <div id="gender">
                            <p>Please select your gender:</p>
                            <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="Male" required>
                            <label for="male">Male</label><br>
                            <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="Female">
                            <label for="female">Female</label><br>
                        </div>
                        <div id="bmi-age">
                            <label for="">Age</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="form-inputs">
                        <label for="">Height(inches)</label><br>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="height" id="height" required>
                        <label for="">Weight(lb)</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="weight" id="weight" required>
                    </div>
                    <button id="bmi-submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div> 
            <p id="bmi-value"></p>  
        </div>
```

Could it be the form submission issue as well?

I want it to display the proper bmi status as the bmi value changes. Instead, it never update the innerHTML after the first submission.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the "bmistatus" p exist, if not then we create a new p, else we editing the existing one

```js
let heightEl = document.getElementById("height");
let weightEl = document.getElementById("weight");

let bmidisplayEl = document.getElementById("bmi-value");
let bmisubmitEl = document.getElementById("bmi-submit");
bmisubmitEl.addEventListener("click",bmiCalc);

function bmiCalc(){
    let heightSquare =Math.pow(Number(heightEl.value), 2);
    let bmiResult = Math.floor(Number(weightEl.value)*703/heightSquare);
    //get the bmistatus p element
    let bmiStatus = document.querySelector("#bmistatus");
    //if no bmiStatus element is found, then we create a new p
    if (bmiStatus == undefined){
        bmiStatus = document.createElement("p");
        bmiStatus.setAttribute("id","bmistatus");
        let bmiBody = document.getElementById("bmi");
        bmiBody.appendChild(bmiStatus);
    }

    bmidisplayEl.innerHTML =`Your bmi is ${bmiResult}`;
    if (bmiResult <= 18.5){
        bmiStatus.innerHTML=`Underweight`;
    }else if(bmiResult >= 25){
        bmiStatus.innerHTML=`Overweight`;
    }
    else{
        bmiStatus.innerHTML=`Healthy`;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="bmi">
  <h1>BMI Calculator</h1>
  <div id="bmi-form-container">
    <form action="" onsubmit="event.preventDefault()">
      <div id="top-row">
        <div id="gender">
          <p>Please select your gender:</p>
          <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="Male" required>
          <label for="male">Male</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="Female">
          <label for="female">Female</label><br>
        </div>
        <div id="bmi-age">
          <label for="age">Age</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="" id="age" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="form-inputs">
        <label for="height">Height(inches)</label><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="height" id="height" required>
        <label for="weight">Weight(lb)</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="weight" id="weight" required>
      </div>
      <button id="bmi-submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <p id="bmi-value"></p>
</div>
```

---

**Edit** : I add a gif where we see that the bmiStatus changes as expected
[image: gif where we see that the bmiStatus changes]

Comment: There is a typo (coming from OP's code) in `}else if(bmiResult =>25){` where the operator should be `>=` -- And that makes me "overweight", so please fix it ;)

Comment: Problem still persists. If you input height and weight, the "bmiStatus" p element does show your bmi status. But the second time if you change those numbers, the bmiValue change, the the "bmiStatus" wouldn't change.

Comment: I added a gif to my answer where we see that the bmiStatus changes correctly. What are the values you put in the fields?